# Is it possible to reference class member variables using an index in C#?

Tags: c#, class, variables, indexing, member

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string city;
    public string state;
    public string zip;
}
```

And I'm performing a data dip on a database:

```
Select Name, Address, City, State, Zip
FROM Persons_Tbl
```

Currently, I am storing the data in the class like this:

```
// Person class and SqlDataReader have been instantiated.

while (reader.Read())
{
    p.name = reader[0].ToString();
    p.address = reader[1].ToString();
    p.city = reader[2].ToString();
    p.state = reader[3].ToString();
    p.zip = reader[4].ToString();
}
```

This is just an example.  In reality, I have more columns to retrieve. Rather than writing one line for each column data dip, I'd like to make the code smaller and loop, via an index.  This is possible using the reader object, since I can retrieve columns via an index.

However, is it possible to index class member variables in the same manner?  Here is the rewritten while loop, to better explain what I am asking:

```
// pseudocode!
while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        index of p member variables (i.e. name, address) = reader[index].ToString();   
    }
}
```

Is it possible to manipulate class member variables in this manner?  Or, must I create a member variable that is an array type?  I'd prefer to write out each member variable of the Person class, since it looks cleaner and is easier to read.

Thank you very much, in advance.

Comment: Well where would you specify which index mapped to which value? That's what your pseudocode doesn't show...

Comment: Well, what I'm asking is how can I realize what your proposing?  Innately, the SqlData Reader class can reference columns via the index or the column name.  When I reference a member variable, I have to type out the variable.  I want to know if it is possible to reference class member variables via an index, innately, as opposed to writing out the variable.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not proposing anything. I'm saying that your "index of p member variables" part doesn't make sense at the moment. What's to say that 0 means name and 1 means address? You'd need to be able to specify that *somewhere*...

Comment: Thank you.  Okay, so that answers my question: No, there is no innate method to reference member variables via their index.  Again, the reader object has this capability built-in -- I can specify the name or the index.  For the Person class, I have to create a mapping.  Or, redesign and consider using an array.

Comment: Variables don't *have* an index. Readers are different - you've specified the names *in a particular order* in the query. The idea that fields would be indexed by their position in source code (if that's what you were thinking) is really brittle.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are just perfectly correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that.

Example:

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string city;
    public string state;
    public string zip;

    public string this[int index] { //SPECIAL PROPERTY INDEXERS
        get {
           if(index == 0)
              return name;
           else if(index == 1)
              return address;
           ...
        }
        set {
           if(index == 0)
              name = value;
           else if(index == 1)
              address = value;
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

What you use here is called [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `C#`.

after can use it like:

```
Person person = new Person();
person[0] = "James Bond"; //SET NAME
person[1] = "London";     //SET ADDRESS
.....
```

Even considering this, may be, original way to resolve this problem, I would first think about possible ways re-architecting the code to avoid this type of solutions.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, this looks great.  I will heed your advice and think about re-architecting the code.  But this is certainly a worthy solution.  Thanks again.